# Freezer gets too warm at times on adaptive defrost

Tags: refrigerator

I have a brand new GE GTS model, Garage ready, 21.9 cu ft refrigerator freezer-Freezer on top.
The unit works fine for a few days and then, every 3rd or 4th day, the freezer will go from -6 F
to +50 degrees F. This is during the adaptive defrost cycle. The refrigerator section stays within
normal range. GE has replaced the Heater Defrost unit in the freezer, and the main board twice.

But the problem still exists. Tonight the freezer went from -6 degrees F to 55 degrees F.
Any thoughts as to the problem??

Comment: Sounds like the thermostat, temp control, on the freezer coil is off.

Comment: "Brand new" == call the dealer, make them fix it under warranty. While you have already tried this, it's still not fixed, so they either need to fix it right or give you a new unit that actually works right, or a full refund so you can buy one from some other company that works right.

Comment: See if your locale has "lemon laws" - special rules may apply if they have tried to fix it 3 times (typically) and failed to fix it.